# JPA 2.0/Hibernate: Cascade Merge Operation setting null values on children Entities

Tags: spring-batch, jpa-2.0, one-to-many, cascade, hibernate-4.x

I have an entity graph simplified on the diagram below:

[image]

The cascade merge is configured for all entities with oneToMany / oneToOne relationships except from **C** to **D** (because this impacts requirements on other parts of the system). I'm using a spring batch [`JpaItemWriter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.java) with the overridden `doWrite` method below that simply manually calls a merge on all **D** entities:

```
protected void doWrite(EntityManager entityManager, List<? extends A> items) {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Writing to JPA with " + items.size() + " items.");
        }

        if (!items.isEmpty()) {
            long mergeCount = 0;
            for (A item : items) {
                if (!entityManager.contains(item)) {
                    entityManager.merge(item);

                    for(B b : item.getBs()){
                        for(D d : b.getC().getDs()){
                             entityManager.merge(item);             
                        }   
                    }


                    mergeCount++;
                }
            }
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug(mergeCount + " entities merged.");
                logger.debug((items.size() - mergeCount) + " entities found in persistence context.");
            }
        }

    }
```

The Problem is when the merge on **A** is called I can see on the debug tool that all member variables on some **D** entities as set to null resulting of course on a exception because the foreign key to **C** is required. I couldn't found a reason yet but suspect of the merge messing all the children of new **C** entities. With the cascade.MERGE set from **C** to **D** everything works fine. Any hint on this issue? I am using hibernate 4.12

Comment: Have you tried simply switching to the `HibernateItemWriter` (which calls `saveOrUpdate(Object entity)`) and adding Hibernate's `CascadeType.UPDATE`... or `ALL`?